# Is this a safe way to use isolation transformer to mitigate neutral to ground voltage?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, grounding

- I work with a TN-S system wiring.
- Main three phase transformer secondary is in Y configuration.
- A single-phase lab instrument equipment installation requires less than 1 V for neutral to ground.
- We can't provide it even though we're up to code in terms of voltage drop, cross-section, earthing loop impedance etc.

They advised us to use an isolation transformer.

Adding a jumper from neutral to ground of isolation transformer secondary solves the neutral-earth voltage difference. And the ground connected isolation transformer secondary is also connected to the "primary" PE. Not providing isolation but preventing the supposedly harmful voltage difference. Making it look like this:

[image: "isolation" transformer]

Is this a safe and sensible way to go? Protection upstream of isolation transformer is omitted in the diagram (earth leakage, overcurrent, overload, under-voltage, overvoltage protection used).

If there's earth leakage, sum of the current in L1' and N' is not zero so RCBO trips, right?

Thanks.

Comment: *Protection upstream of isolation transformer is omitted* <-- it will be required.

Comment: I meant that it is not shown in my diagram. Sorry for the misleading wording.

Comment: I think it would be OK but, I'd be concerned about the overall PE impedance due to what seems might be a significant extension to the wiring that might necessitate an extra earth rod and breaking of the PE back to the earth rod on the left.

Comment: Yes, RCBO should trip. However one weak point of the configuration is that secondary of isolation transformer is not protected by RCBO. That part of the system will not be isolated from mains and is dangerous if it is somehow accessible.

Comment: @Andyaka The extension will not be more than 10 meters or so and I'll use 6 mm2 PE cable anyways (for sturdiness and code reasons). Something else concerns me is that if the socket of the equipment is flipped - will it affect my setup and instead create a whopping 230 V voltage difference between the equipment's supposed neutral and earth? The device is Agilent 8890 to be specific.

Comment: @NoobPointerException Thankfully the transformer and the RCBO and other protection devices will be inside a locked electrical panel. To protect the transformer secondary I can only use overcurrent and overload protection devices. Of course their trip points should be less than the saturation of the transformer. I wonder if an undervoltage protection device would help, since a short in the transformer secondary leads to a voltage avalanche - is this assumption correct? Is it even used in practice?

Comment: Overcurrent sounds better to me, if overloaded the secondary voltage will sink, but it's hard to tell how much and how quickly, so current is probably a better indicator. I'm not familiar with the term avalanche outside of diodes.

Comment: @NoobPointerException I meant the voltage sink actually by "avalanche".